# Team Speak Installation Problem: Verifying Archive Integrity... Error

Tags: software-installation, archive, teamspeak

I have recently been trying to install Team Speak 3, I allowed as executable then ran it in terminal. I accepted the agreement but this message pops up:

```
Creating directory TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64
Verifying archive integrity...
Error in MD5 checksums: 
155c2fa97063698bee36bdc803791032 is different from 269593c28278de5b34a20b1d45ae6c99
```

I do not quite understand what it means or how to fix it, I would really like to get Team Speak working is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I do not know specifics for this application but typically it means that the downloaded application is corrupted.  I see on the Teamspeak page https://www.teamspeak.com/downloads that checksums are given for each of the downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Error in MD5 checksums is usually when the installion file is corrupt or has been edited. I would recommend you to [downlaod](https://www.teamspeak.com/downloads)  it from again from the offical website.